# Standardized fetch function to communicate with API

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I wrote my server backend in PHP. Now I want to create the communication between frontend (typescript) and backend.

I would like to receive a standardized response for each of my API requests. Accordingly, each response from my server is structured like this:

```
type Response<T> = {
    status: boolean,
    statusCode: number | null,
    statusText: string | null,
    statusDetails: string | null,
    data: T | null
};
```

Important: Since not all API requests return data (e.g. `login` and `logout`), the key `data` can also be null.
If data is available, it should be of generic type `T`. This type depends on the API request. Example:

```
type ApiInitData = {
    user: {
        online: boolean | null,
        name: string | null,
        userGroupName: string | null,
        language: string | null,
        decimals: number | null,
    },
    language: {
        supportedLanguages: string[];
        defaultLanguage: string
    }
}
```

So if the API request was successful, I want to get an object of type `Response<ApiInitData>`. In this case the key `data` in `Response<T>` is not `null` of course.

My goal is to use a Typescript function that returns a Promise. In the `.then` of the Promise I want to control the further processing (e.g. display error message).
Example:

```
Api.login(username, password).then((response) => {
    if(response.status === true){
        // Ok
    }else{
        // Some error has occurred.
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        console.log(response.statusText);
    }
});
```

When an error occurs, the Promise should be forced into the `Response<null>` type so that a standardized object is always returned in the end.
This code snippet is my attempt:

```
//
// Example for login
//
static login = (username: string, password: string) => {
        const data = {
            'api': 'login',
            'username': username,
            'password': password
        };
        return this.request<Response<null>>(data);
    }

//
// Example for init data
//
static getInitData = () => {
        const data = {
            'api': 'getInitializationData'
        };
        return this.request<Response<ApiInitData | null>>(data);
    }

//
// Standard request function for all API requests.
//
static request = <T>(data: object, options: RequestInit = {}, url: string | null = null) => {
        const requestOptions = this.prepareRequest(data, options, url);
        return fetch(requestOptions.url, requestOptions.options)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json() as Promise<T>;
                } else {
                    const result: Response<null> = {
                        status: false,
                        statusCode: response.status,
                        statusText: response.statusText,
                        statusDetails: null,
                        data: null,
                    }
                    return new Promise<Response<null>>((resolve) => { resolve(result) });
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                const result: Response<null> = {
                    status: false,
                    statusCode: 503,
                    statusText: error,
                    statusDetails: null,
                    data: null,
                }
                return new Promise<Response<null>>((resolve) => { resolve(result) });
            });
    }
```

The typescript compiler throws this error message:
**The argument of type "(response: Response) => Promise | Promise<Response>" cannot be assigned to the parameter of type "(value: Response) => T | PromiseLike".** (line 4 of my request function).

I've no idea how to fix it. So I've two questions:

- How  can I fix the error ?
- Is my approach used a common solution to this problem? Or is a completely different approach currently recommended here?

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the first question: The function given to `.then()` returns `Promise<T>` in case of success but `Promise<Response<null>>` in case of error. To just fix the error you could explicity state the desired types like

```js
.then(function(response): Promise<T | Response<null>> { ...
```

But it looks like you want to return `Promise<Response<T>>` in both cases (in order to evaluate `response.status === true` as mentioned). The result of `response.json()` would then need to be wrapped by a `Response<T>` in the same way as the error.

Concerning the second question: The way you approach this here is a pattern [known](https://jrsinclair.com/articles/2019/elegant-error-handling-with-the-js-either-monad/) [as](https://itnext.io/either-monad-a-functional-approach-to-error-handling-in-js-ffdc2917ab2) [Either Monad](https://monad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/types/either.html).

edit: Cleared up the answer about the possible options.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, I have now found a working solution for me. I now return `Promise.resolve` and force its type to `T`.

`return Promise.resolve(result as unknown as T);`

```
static request = <T>(data: object, options: RequestInit = {}, url: string | null = null) => {
        const requestOptions = this.prepareRequest(data, options, url);
        return fetch(requestOptions.url, requestOptions.options)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json() as Promise<T>;
                } else {
                    const result: Response<null> = {
                        status: false,
                        statusCode: response.status,
                        statusText: response.statusText,
                        statusDetails: null,
                        data: null,
                    }
                    return Promise.resolve(result as unknown as T);
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                const result: Response<null> = {
                    status: false,
                    statusCode: 503,
                    statusText: error,
                    statusDetails: error,
                    data: null,
                }
                console.log(error);
                return Promise.resolve(result as unknown as T);
            });
    }
```